# Jogging beginner

Tags: running, jogging, beginners

I'm not a complete couch potato but I don't exercise near enough either. I'm skinny and around 170 cm (or 5 feet, 7 inches). I would like to start a jogging schedule but I have no idea where to start and I haven't done it in the past. Also at what speed is jogging actually jogging and not walking/running? So my questions are:

1) When do i go jogging? For how long? How does this increase?
2) What distance/time ratio is qualified as a "jogging speed" ?
3) Is it ok to drink water while jogging?
4) Are running shoes very important to the jogging experience? Especially when you're just starting out and not doing it consistently.

Comment: Speed doesnt differentiate running from walking. Ive finished marathons jogging (refusing to walk) at a pace slower than I can walk briskly. What defines them is the type of movement. See Merriam-Webster definition for run:" to go steadily by springing steps so that both feet leave the ground for an instant in each step"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was always active when I was younger but it was until I hit my 30s that I finally decided to dig in and start running.  The first thing I'd advise is to use a workout such as Couch 2 5K which helps ease you in to the whole process of running/jogging.

It is a great interval trainer that will get you running a 5K in 9 weeks.  It really helped me want to continue to run since I progressed every week and didn't feel like death.

As for shoes, don't Google anything ... seriously.  I went down this road and wanted to find that "perfect" shoe for my foot - High Arches/Supinate - I even had orthotics for a long time period.  Anyways, what I've come to find out is it's trying and training in shoes that really lets you know what works for you.  For Instance I love Nike Free's for that barefoot/minimalist feel but also dig Acsics Gel-Nimbus for a more cushioned ride.

In the end, ease in to it and take your time.  Make sure you can have a conversation while jogging, this will let you know if you're going too hard.  But yea, ease in and enjoy!

Comment: +1 for C25k, and interestingly studies are starting to show that a comfortable shoe is more beneficial than ones picked for "stride/gait analysis" outcomes.

Comment: thanks for your recommendations, I've already bookmarked the schedule and am looking forward to becoming an addict!

Answer (score 1):

1) Whenever you feel like it. For however long you feel comfortable doing it. As you get into a routine, your stamina will increase and you'll be able to exercise for longer and at a higher intensity.

2) There's not, as it's something totally dependant on an individual and his/her specific conditions. But the more that you run, the faster that you'll be able to do it after some time.

3) Sure, but do it too much and it may end up bothering your stomach.

4) They are important in the sense that if you run with some awfully uncomfortable $5 sneakers that end up destroying your feet after each run you may not feel like running again for a while. I would not advise a beginner to buy any $100-$200 shoes until they know for sure they like running and will be doing it consistently.

Comment: Gave you an upvote even if it doesn't show since my rep is still under 15. Thanks for your answers, they've been enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would not worry too much about all these details. Just go out and (warm up and) start running!

1. Any time you feel comfortable. If you are a morning person, go early morning. You will feel fresh throughout the day.
2. You can not run faster than your maximum speed.. Try running a bit slower than your max, so that you can maintain it for a longer duration.
3. It helps to drink water a little, energy drink helps more :) Don't empty more than one bottle during one run though.
4. As long as they are comfortable, any shoes are fine. You can try insoles too. They are very soft.

Make sure to enjoy it. Make a playlist of your favorite songs/ audio book.. get a buddy to run with you.. set targets, compete with yourself.. anything you like and you will have fun :)